# In our spring batch application, we have to download,read,process,write and upload file. my question is how to stop read upload when download failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have download and upload methods in joblistener.java
We have only one step. Inside it we have read,process,write.
How to fail next operations when prior operations are failing.
For example, how to stop executing read,process,write,upload when download is failed?

Answer (score 0):

Move the download out of the job listener and into it's own step that runs before the processing step.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the read to be the determinant on whether the application should proceed to the flow (process and writer). To do that, you can either return null or throw a runtime exception to stop the flow.

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#stoppingAJobManuallyForBusinessReasons